# compare and merge the datatable in C#

Tags: c#

I have a two different Datatables

```
datatable1: customer, product, shippedqty
datatable2: customer, product, febforecast, marforecast, aprforecast
```

Here  Customer and product columns are same

I need to compare `datatable1` with `datatable2`  on `customer` and `products` columns and i need to get the result set into new `datatable` as

```
customer,product,dhipedqty,febforecast,marforecast,aprforecast
```

This is what i've tried:

```
var tablesJoinend = from t1 in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() 
                    join t2 in forecastdatatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() 
                    on new { A = t1["Customer"].ToString(), B = t1["ProductCode"].ToString() } 
                    equals new { A = t2["customer"].ToString(), B = t2["NDC"].ToString() } 
                    select t1;
```

Now i have tried this which it was not worked

```
var results = from t1 in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                              join t2 in forecastdatatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() on new { A = t1["Customer"].ToString(), B = t1["ProductCode"].ToString() } equals new { A = t2["customer"].ToString(), B = t2["NDC"].ToString() }
                              select new
                              {
                                  CustID = Convert.ToInt32(t1["Customer"]),
                                  ColX = Convert.ToInt32(t1["ProductCode"]),
                                  ColY = Convert.ToInt32(t1[3]),
                                  a = Convert.ToInt32(t1[4]),
                                  xx = Convert.ToInt32(t2[4]),
                                    qq = Convert.ToInt32(t2[5])
                              };
```

Comment: var tablesJoinend = from t1 in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                    join t2 in forecastdatatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() on new { A = t1["Customer"].ToString(), B = t1["ProductCode"].ToString() } equals new { A = t2["customer"].ToString(), B = t2["NDC"].ToString() }
                                    select t1;

Comment: thant for the link but in that example they have compared only one column but i want to compare two columns at the same time

Comment: So you have tried something. But did it work? If not you should tell us what's wrong with it. As far as i can see you are selecting `t1` which are the rows of `dt` and not the forecast rows. But you want columns of both tables. So you could select an anonymous type that contains both rows. Then use a `foreach`-loop to fill your third table.

Comment: can you please give me the loop how to start it so that it will help me